# MS Word Section Numbering (e.g. A.1.1) includes Chapter (A.1) but not Changing with Chapter Number

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a large document with sections>chapters>subsection

The first subsection in Chapter B.1 should be numbered B.1.1. I get 1.13 or something like that. This figure shows the config window in the process of being edited:

[image: config window]

In fact, when I do "include level number from" > Level 2 (my chapters are Level 2), it does not show "A.1" in "enter formatting for number", it shows just "1" and stays "1" for all the sections and chapters.

What might be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

---

More details:

I'm using Word 2013 on Windows 10. The sections are numbered A, B, ... Chapters are numbered A.1, A.2, ... B.1, B.2... I want my subsections to read A.1.1, A.1.2..., A.2.1,..., B.1.1... But when I go and try to do it through "define new multilevel list" the chapter number does not change in section number.

Answer (score 1):

For level 1:
- click level to modify (1)
 - number style for this level (A,B,C,..)

For level 2:
 - click level to modify (2)
 - include level number from (Level 1)
 - add (.)
 - number style for this level (1,2,3,..)

For level 3:
 - click level to modify (3)
 - include level number from (Level 1)
 - add (.)
 - include level number from (Level 2)
 - add (.)
 - number style for this level (1,2,3,..)

...etc.

Answer (score 0):

For your third level B.1.1 you need to "include level number from" for both parts of your second level B.1 (ie not just level 2).

So you would have "include level number from" Level 1 (to get the A), then type the full stop, then "include level number from" Level 2 (to get the 1), then type the full stop, and then you would choose "Number style for this level" as 1,2,3...